# WPF Datagrid selecteditem = null in MVVM

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, datagrid, selecteditem

I'm trying to work with a datagrid using the MVVM pattern. The problem is that whenever I change the VM property which is binded to SelectedItem to null, the View doesn't "deselect" the currently selected item. This is my binding in xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

The SelectedItem binding works from the view to the VM thus in the SelectedUser property I always have the selected object. The problem is that in the VM I'm doing some stuff which sometimes changes the SelectedUser property to null so I would expect the datagrid to deselect the row as well. Instead, it remains selected and if I try to click on the same row, the property doesn't update. If I click on any other row, the property changes as expected.

Is there a way to make the datagrid deselect if it's binded property is set to null? Also I'm looking for a MVVM solution as I don't want to write code behind. I can solve this by writing code behind so don't waste time offering such solutions :)

l.e.: this is my property in the VM:

```
public RPLUser SelectedUser
        {
            get
            {                
                return selectedUser;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedUser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you set the property in your viewmodel are you calling the OnPropertyChanged event to let the View know it needs to update?

Comment: Yes, I'm editing the description to mention this as well. Good question, thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to set the property in your VM and also the code for the property itself?

Comment: Setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your binding might help.

Comment: I would try OnPropertyChanged("");  Could be something weird is going on with the binding but that does look ok.  Have you tried breakpointing the set to see if the SelectedUser gets set again sometime after you have set it to NULL? Also make sure you are setting the SelectedUser property and not the variable it returns.

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger didn't solve the problem. I've tried it with all it's possible values, including PropertyChanged. Also tried OnPropertyChanged(""). This didn't solve it either. Made sure I'm setting the property to null, not the private field and also made sure it remains null and no other component is setting it back.

Comment: Solved it. It turned out I was not setting the SelectedUser property to null but to a "new User()". Solved it by first setting it to null and then creating a new object for it. Purplegoldfish's answer lead me to the solution so please post an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend to check the `Output Window` in visual studio and see if any `Binding` is failing.

Are you sure when you select something, the selection updates into the `SelectedUser` property?

Did u put a breakpoint in setter of `SelectedUser` and see that it is hitting when you select something on the datagrid?

The reasons for this `Binding` to break could be many ...

1. `SelectedUser` is of different type than individual `Users`.
2. `SelectedUser` does not match by reference with any items in `Users`.
3. How and where are you setting null?

The following code in my case works perfectly fine...

```
    <tk:DataGrid MaxHeight="200" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding MySelItem,
                                        ElementName=MyDGSampleWindow,
                                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                 IsReadOnly="True">
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Key"
                                   Binding="{Binding Key,
                                                     Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
                                   Binding="{Binding Value,
                                                     Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
```

When I set `MyDGSampleWindow.MySelItem` as null, the datagrid propertly deselects. Perhaps you might need to give us more input on how are you actually setting the value as null.

Comment: You are right, I was not setting the property to null as I should have. I was creating a new object instead of setting it to null. Solved it by first setting the property to null and then giving it a new object. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Did you try setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` in the xaml properties for the DataGrid? AFAIK, this will allow you to unselect it by setting the SelectedUser to null.
I cannot test it at the moment, but you could also try to add this in the setter of your property:

```
set
{
    selectedUser = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");

    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Users);
    collectionView.MoveCurrentTo(selectedUser);

}
```

(For `ICollectionView` to do anything, you will need to have `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` set)
Like I said, I cannot test this right now. Also, the setter of the property is probably not the best place to put it. Maybe create an event handler for the `PropertyChanged`event locally and put that logic there.

Let me know if it helps, else I'll see if I can run a short test...

Comment: I had a similar problem and settiing  `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` worked for me !!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah may need to add the XAML UpdateSourceTrigger to update the UI.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGrid will not Deselect it automatically as `DataGridRow`'s `IsSelected` property should be set to `False`.

You can do that by Setting a style on DataGrid.. like

```
    <Style x:Key="dataGridRowStyle"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type WPFToolkit:DataGridRow}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type WPFToolkit:DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
```

The `IsSelected` property should be the of the object i.e in your case `RPLUser` should have a property Isselected

Then before you set the `SelectedUser` to null... just do `SelectedUser.IsSelected=False`

And dont forget to attach this style to the `DataGridRowStyle` in Datagrid

I am using WPFToolkit you can modify the style if you are targetting `.NET 4.0`

Comment: you can remove the BasedOn `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type WPFToolkit:DataGridRow}}"`

Comment: This doesnt look to be an issue of datagrid row's not getting deselected. I just checked it, and in basic setup the datagrid deselects when selected item is set to null via Binding.

Comment: @AngelWPF i tried to do it tat way but it was not working so i tried it the Style way